# Thermostat to control electrical baseboard heater

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, thermostat, 120-240v

I wanna install 8 electrical baseboard heaters. So I need 3 circuits so I won’t over load them. So I wanna know if there’s a way to just install one thermostat

Comment: Why are you using electric baseboard heat to begin with, if I may ask? (Instead of, say, a mini-split or two)

Comment: How much power are those heaters, one thermostat for all, or each gets one

Comment: Are they all in the same room

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Other than this being *pure madness* unless you have free electricity, it's a common enough install from when electricity was "going to be too cheap to meter" and lots of baseboard was put in. These days, a cold-climate (or your-climate if not cold,) or ground-source heat pump makes far more economic sense.

Anyway, you have a single thermostat that controls relays or "contactors" for each circuit. Typically that's a 24VAC thermostat circuit, and the relays have 24VAC control coils, and contacts rated for 240VAC @ 20A resistive. Commonly they are mounted adjacent to the breaker panel supplying the power, so that when they are off, only a few inches of cable from the breaker to the relay are energized.